How to remove overfull within the align environment
Here is the MRE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\listfiles

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in, top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{dsfont}

\overfullrule 5pt

%\doublespacing

\UseRawInputEncoding


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
p_x &= \mathbb{P}(d_{ij} \geq a) = 1 - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a) +      \mathbb{P}(d_{ij} = a) = \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(b) - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a) + \mathbb{P}(d_{ij} = a) \\
q_x &= \mathbb{P}(d_{XY} \leq b) = \hat{F}_{d_{XY}}(b) \\
p'_x &= \mathbb{P}(d_{ij} \geq a') + \mathbb{P}(d_{XY} = a) = 1 - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a') + \mathbb{P}(d_{XY} = a) = \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(b) - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a') + \mathbb{P}(d_{XY} = a)  \\
q'_x &= \mathbb{P}(d'_{XY} \leq b) = \hat{F}_{d'_{XY}}(b)
\end{align}

\end{document}


Any suggestions?

Remove the split environment and use align only

you should also provide an example that shows the overfull box, being overfull is a function of the page size, you could make a small complete 1-page document that shows the problem and allows peopel to test answers

@Mane32 True, but the overfull still persists.

@DavidCarlisle Done.

That doesn't show the page size.  A complete example from \documentclass through \end{document} would help us answer the question and make sure that our answers work for your case.

@Teepeemm Revised,

Unrelated but \UseRawInputEncoding breaks almost all LaTeX's support for character input, it has some very specific legacy use cases where you need to disable the standard handling as a package implements its own. but don't routinely add this.

I'd split the overlong line at the last equals sign. Possibly also the first line, for symmetry.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\listfiles

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}% <--- WHY?
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in, top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}

%\usepackage{hyperref}% should be last anyway


%\overfullrule 5pt

%\doublespacing

%\UseRawInputEncoding <--- NO!!!

\newcommand{\PR}{\mathbb{P}}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
p_x  &= \PR(d_{ij} \geq a)
      = 1 - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a) + \PR(d_{ij} = a)
      = \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(b) - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a) + \PR(d_{ij} = a) \\
q_x  &= \PR(d_{XY} \leq b) = \hat{F}_{d_{XY}}(b) \\
p'_x &= \PR(d_{ij} \geq a') + \PR(d_{XY} = a)
      = 1 - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a') + \PR(d_{XY} = a) \notag \\
     &= \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(b) - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a') + \PR(d_{XY} = a)  \\
q'_x &= \PR(d'_{XY} \leq b) = \hat{F}_{d'_{XY}}(b)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
p_x  &= \PR(d_{ij} \geq a)
      = 1 - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a) + \PR(d_{ij} = a) \notag \\
     &= \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(b) - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a) + \PR(d_{ij} = a) \\
q_x  &= \PR(d_{XY} \leq b) = \hat{F}_{d_{XY}}(b) \\
p'_x &= \PR(d_{ij} \geq a') + \PR(d_{XY} = a)
      = 1 - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a') + \PR(d_{XY} = a) \notag \\
     &= \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(b) - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a') + \PR(d_{XY} = a)  \\
q'_x &= \PR(d'_{XY} \leq b) = \hat{F}_{d'_{XY}}(b)
\end{align}

\end{document}


If you don't have space constraints, I'd also consider splitting at all equals signs.
\begin{align}
p_x  &= \PR(d_{ij} \geq a) \notag \\
     &= 1 - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a) + \PR(d_{ij} = a) \notag \\
     &= \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(b) - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a) + \PR(d_{ij} = a) \\[1ex]
q_x  &= \PR(d_{XY} \leq b) \notag \\
     &= \hat{F}_{d_{XY}}(b) \\[1ex]
p'_x &= \PR(d_{ij} \geq a') + \PR(d_{XY} = a) \notag \\
     &= 1 - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a') + \PR(d_{XY} = a) \notag \\
     &= \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(b) - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a') + \PR(d_{XY} = a)  \\[1ex]
q'_x &= \PR(d'_{XY} \leq b) \notag \\
     &= \hat{F}_{d'_{XY}}(b)
\end{align}



I like this answer! The result is very easy to read and follow.

You can split the long line, for example with gathered

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\listfiles

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in, top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{dsfont}

\overfullrule 5pt

%\doublespacing

% NO!!!!!!!!!!!!\UseRawInputEncoding


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
p_x &= \mathbb{P}(d_{ij} \geq a) = 1 - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a) +      \mathbb{P}(d_{ij} = a) = \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(b) - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a) + \mathbb{P}(d_{ij} = a) \\
q_x &= \mathbb{P}(d_{XY} \leq b) = \hat{F}_{d_{XY}}(b) \\
  p'_x &=
         \begin{gathered}[t]
           \mathbb{P}(d_{ij} \geq a') + \mathbb{P}(d_{XY} = a) 
           = 1 - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a') + \mathbb{P}(d_{XY} = a) = \\
           \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(b) - \hat{F}_{d_{ij}}(a') + \mathbb{P}(d_{XY} = a)
           \end{gathered}\\
q'_x &= \mathbb{P}(d'_{XY} \leq b) = \hat{F}_{d'_{XY}}(b)
\end{align}

\end{document}


Thanks - also for your comment regarding \UseRawInputEncoding
